# onSharedPreferenceChanged and PreferenceFragment

Tags: android

Trying to follow the examples given in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html but finding it difficult as it arbitrarily flips between using and not using fragments.

I've taken its advice to use fragments when implementing Preferences for my app as I'm using the most recent SDK (16)

I'm trying to implement `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method such that I can update the preference summaries when a user chages a preference value.

should I implement the callback method in the fragment or the parent Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are supporting API levels from 11 to 16, `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method has to be only implemented in your fragment.

You should only implement this method on activity in case you are supporting lower API levels.